# R Merging data frames sequentially summing elemets - tricky.

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I have a series of data frames that I want to merge, sequentially summing specific elements. For background, these are individual partition files for genomic sequence data that reference gene regions along an alignment (think of it as sections of a string). I have merged the sequence alignments together so need to merge the partition files together while retaining the partitions relative positions. It would be good to make this as general as possible to accommodate any number, and length, of individual partition files.

The merging and summing need to work something like this:

1. The second column elements are the preceding row's third column element plus one.
2. For the first data frame, third column: first element equals n, second element equals 2n, third element is 3n, and so on.
3. In the newly merged data frame the first element of the third column would become its value (x) plus the last element of the third column in the previous dataframe (x + ?n). x is then added to x + ?n for each row until the end of the data frame or a new one is merged.

A simple example will explain better.

Here is a data frame for Region 1:

```
                  V1    V2    V3 
Region_1_Partition_1     1   500
Region_1_Partition_2   501  1000
Region_1_Partition_3  1001  1500
```

And here is Region 2:

```
                  V1    V2   V3 
Region_2_Partition_1     1  200
Region_2_Partition_2   201  400
Region_2_Partition_3   401  600
```

The final partition file needs to be this:

```
                  V1    V2    V3 
Region_1_Partition_1     1   500
Region_1_Partition_2   501  1000
Region_1_Partition_3  1001  1500
Region_2_Partition_1  1501  1700
Region_2_Partition_2  1701  1900
Region_2_Partition_3  1901  2001
```

I guess there are a number of neat solutions that have eluded me so far!

Thanks 
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry, I usually browse data.table() specific questions and failed to notice that this question is about data frames!  Changed my answer accordingly

I would keep the "n" as a column so that you can `cumsum()` it in the final frame.  Which I would not achieve by `merge` but rather by `rbind()`

First "recreating" your data

```
region1 <- data.frame(
  label=c('Region_1_Partition_1', 'Region_1_Partition_2', 
'Region_1_Partition_3'),
  V4=500
)

region1$V3 <- cumsum(region1$V4)
region1$V2 <- region1$V3 - region1$V4 + 1
region1[, c('label', 'V2', 'V3')]
```

That last command returns

```
                  label   V2   V3
1: Region_1_Partition_1    1  500
2: Region_1_Partition_2  501 1000
3: Region_1_Partition_3 1001 1500
```

Similar code, with `V4=200` can give region2.

Now to perform your combination,

```
out <- rbind(region1[, c('label', 'V4')], region2[, c('label', 'V4')])

out$V3 <- cumsum(out$V4)
out$V2 <- out$V3 - out$V4 + 1
out[, c('label', 'V2', 'V3')]


                  label   V2   V3
1: Region_1_Partition_1    1  500
2: Region_1_Partition_2  501 1000
3: Region_1_Partition_3 1001 1500
4: Region_2_Partition_1 1501 1700
5: Region_2_Partition_2 1701 1900
6: Region_2_Partition_3 1901 2100
```

ANOTHER EDIT: How to scale the solution to greater numbers of partitions.

I can see two challenges here, the first being the need to `rbind()` all the stuff and the second being the need to determine what to use in the `V4` column.

There may be a more efficient R way of doing this (something like storing all the tables in a list and then flattening them down to one table).  I would just use a for loop.

Let's say you have all your filenames in a vector called `files`.

```
out <- data.frame()
for (file in files) {

  # read the file. prepend a path before this step if necessary
  data <- read.csv(file)

  # determine V4.  This assumes that V3 is guaranteed to have a constant difference in any given file 
  # and that the first row is that difference, as in your example data
  data$V4 <- data$V3[1]

  data <- data[, c('V1', 'V4')] #note that I switched my first colname to match yours

  out <- rbind(out, data)
}

# Recover V2 and V3
out$V3 <- cumsum(out$V4)
out$V2 <- out$V3 - out$V4 + 1
out[, c('V1', 'V2', 'V3')]
```

Note that your files have to be in order, or else the `cumsum()` will not be right.  If the files are not in order, you can re-order them after building te `out` table and before using `cumsum()`

Comment: Just tried this and works well. Do you have suggestions for scaling up - say I had 20+ individual partition files in .csv?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include my attempt to address this